# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - GIMP

Tags: software-installation, gimp, segmentation-fault

Running 15.10 / 32bit

I tried to install Gimp via PPA / with `sudo apt-get install gimp` and with Software center too. Each time after I uninstalled gimp, I used Purge command. And each time i tried to open it I got "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Any other methods to try? I saw there are many cases out there similar with this, but none helped in my situation, couldn't manage to solve the error.

Comment: Not a lot to go on. But http://askubuntu.com/questions/506966/gimp-crashing-on-start is the same with a working answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/532950/15811 See if that is your problem (change the 2.8 to what you need if yours is not 2.8)

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690565/how-to-resolve-segmentation-fault-core-dumped)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue for 1 month, finally today I found how to resolve it.
what I did was installing gdb and gimp-dbg:

```
sudo apt-get install gdb gimp-dbg
```

after that I ran:

```
gdb gimp
(gdb) run
```

it shows that segmentation fault happens from

```
/usr/lib/libamdocl64.so
```

I'm using a proprietary video driver from AMD so this debug message shows that something is wrong with my video driver (opencl sources). I installed latest Ubuntu driver from AMD and everything works again.

P.S. I added debugging steps for you to check if your issue is same or not, but in short if your issue is same, you can only go for installing the latest driver for your video card.

Comment: Got this error `Thread 1 "gimp" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff40abffa in g_markup_parse_context_parse () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0` Do you have an idea how to inspect this problem further?

Comment: @JPT try installing `sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev`